# importing png file in create-react-app is not showing image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, png

I am using create-react-app, I have an asset folder under src folder and I imported a png file frome asset in code, however it's not showing on browser.

My code:

```
    import placeholderImage from "../../assets/placeholder.png";
```

.
.
.

```
  <Image src={placeholderImage} alt="popular series image"></Image>
```

Code for Image component:

```
import React from "react";

const Image = ({ className, ...rest }) => (
    <img {...rest} className={className} />
);

export default Image;
```

What I get on browser:

It renders on html as `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAP4AAACQCAMAAAAftiZJAAAAb1BMVEX///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////+pUA8cAAAAJXRSTlMAAQIDBAUHCAkKCwwNDg8QERIUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8gISIjJCUmQ2v0nAAAActJREFUeNrt3FtTgkAchnFREkQ8JCB4KE77/T9jhrCAMk1JN+z/+d21d0+uL44zNZsBAAAAAAAAAAAAAADg7+Z+uJuLbU9KpVRmi6y3U3UXyXz17Y97fmlJqrYW+vbH9/61nPZ1XGSO/vFQ5cdy2qvbvtFHm1LM7Q8K1TjoQzeXcvvtq85XsdUdQBm334rb/qt+2s9PKje32Ys+H6eu0hnAsDC2/futXfr9qasf9+2pY2K7U7UPTV3tXcSnuv7UvaXt6dHoJ95t1IanTksMfL+Hw1O3bKeuPglc09pXYf6LqdsplYcr09rdIHsateGpcz3zbv3wqDF17ellYfSzLvxp6lQeeSZGb3uj1ii83qmh7TenzqitOlO3bx+GR8/cK5/I/FTXvdvt1C0uYqauDu5PnRXpt3/iSHj5zwNTd2tfC/kGe/v4qc7LxbQ3t1/M1A09+gRN3TO/Gbs0es1+2r+3zhc7r0mn3G+r0YIpf8MzPv8sO/9CPvnkk08++eSTTz755JNPPvnkk08++eSTTz755JNPPvnkk08++eSTTz755JNPPvnkk/8PluPzJ/0PLK6j8yf958x2PC4+82cAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCfQEzfP68mfa5CAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="popular series image">`

but the image is not showing on browser. How to fix this?
PS: I can render svg files using this component only png doesn't work

Comment: What is this <Image> ? 
Try this <img> to confirm .

Comment: I updated to include implementation of Image....its basically an img tag

Comment: And what if you use <img> instead ?

Comment: I have replicated the code and it is rendering. May be something is wrong with the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: The background of Image was transparent :-|